# C - Increment 18 bits in C 8051

Tags: c, embedded, increment, 8051

I have been programming the 8051 for about two months now and am somewhat of a newbie to the C language. I am currently working with flash memory in order to read, write, erase, and analyze it. I am working on the write phase at the moment and one of the tasks that I need to do is specify an address location and fill that location with data then increment to the next location and fill it with complementary data. So on and so forth until I reach the end.

My dilemma is I have 18 address bits to play with and currently have three bytes allocated for those 18 bits. Is there anyway that I could combine those 18 bits into an `int` or `unsigned int` and increment like that? Or is my only option to increment the first byte, then when that byte rolls over to `0x00` increment the next byte and when that one rolls over, increment the next?

I currently have:

```
void inc_address(void)
{
    P6=address_byte1;
    P7=address_byte2;
    P2=address_byte3;
    P5=data_byte;

    while(1)
    {
        P6++;
        if(P6==0x00){P7++;}
        else if(P7==0x00){P2++;}
        else if(P2 < 0x94){break;} //hex 9 is for values dealing with flash chip
        P5=~data_byte;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have bitfields available?  OK, so the 8051 was nearly wiped out on the C-T boundary and has less RAM than a flatlined goldfish, but if you can use 18 bits out of 24 for a bitfield int var, that might do it...

Comment: Your increment looks flawed, if P6 and P7 start at 255 for example, you end up with P6 and p7 = 1 when both should remain zero.  The loop is not necessary - the "carry tests" should be nested.

Comment: It would also be far better to increment the address variable and assign it to the port rather than assigning it to the port and incrementing the port values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway that I could combine those 18 bits into an int or
>   unsigned int and increment like that?

Sure.  Supposing that `int` and `unsigned int` are at least 18 bits wide on your system, you can do this:

```
unsigned int next_address = (hi_byte << 16) + (mid_byte << 8) + low_byte + 1;
hi_byte = next_address >> 16;
mid_byte = (next_address >> 8) & 0xff;
low_byte = next_address & 0xff;
```

The `<<` and `>>` are bitwise shift operators, and the binary `&` is the bitwise "and" operator.

It would be a bit safer and more portable to not make assumptions about the sizes of your types, however.  To avoid that, include `stdint.h`, and use type `uint_least32_t` instead of `unsigned int`:

```
uint_least32_t next_address = ((uint_least32_t) hi_byte << 16)
        + ((uint_least32_t) mid_byte << 8)
        + (uint_least32_t) low_byte
        + 1;

// ...
```

Comment: So you're saying to create a new variable and do bitwise operations on them in order to create the 18 bit variable I need in order to increment. Could you explain why you put the +1 at the end of the first line? I think that should come after and not in the initialization right? The following three lines are just re-defining the original variables but why the bitwise "and" operator?

Comment: You need a place to store the assembled address, because you'll need to access it multiple times to pull out the three bytes of interest.  That requires a variable.  I performed the +1 in the initializer mostly for brevity, and I named the variable in a way intended to be consistent with that initialization.  The +1 could have been done afterward instead; it's just a stylistic choice.  When reading out the updated bytes, the bitwise `&` masks off the unwanted bits.  If the individual byte variables have an unsigned, 8-bit type then such masking is unnecessary, but harmless.

Comment: Okay I understand now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: `hi_byte` should use only the least-significant two bits. Suggest eEither insert `next_address &= 0x3FFFF ;` or change `hi_byte = (next_address >> 16) & 0x03;`.  `unsigned int` is almost certainly 16 bit of an 8051 so too small.

Answer (score 1):

Where `address` is `uint32_t`:

```
void inc_address(void)
{
    // Increment address
    address = (address + 1) & 0x0003ffff ;

    // Assert address A0 to A15
    P6 = (address & 0xff)
    P7 = (address >> 8) & 0xff

    // Set least significant two bits of P2 to A16,A17 
    // without modifying other bits in P2
    P2 &= 0xFC ;                   // xxxxxx00
    P2 |= (address >> 16) & 0x03 ; // xxxxxxAA

    // Set data
    P5 = ~data_byte ;
}
```

However it is not clear why the function is called `inc_address` but also assigns `P5` with `~data_byte`, which presumably asserts the the data bus?  It is doing something more than increment an address it seems, so is poorly and confusingly named.  I suggest also that the function should take address and data as parameters rather than [global data](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals).